# My miniature poodle pulling hair out of his right paw.

Tags: dogs, behavior

My miniature poodle is pulling hair out of his right front paw; now also going after the left one!  This started just before he had cataract surgery and escalated after the surgery.  Yes, he's had some allergies, but they only caused some light licking.  This is a different issue. I spent $430.00 for a veterinary dermatologist to give me some spray to use as needed, and a special shampoo to use. No diagnosis or ideas on behavioral changes.  Anyone else had this problem and able to correct it?  He has a raw spot that the vet cultured. Results in about a week

Comment: I'd suggest waiting for the culture results. This _could just be overgrooming -- akin to biting your fingernails -- which can be a response to stress. Or it could be a skin infection of some kind causing itching.  Or possibly something else. That's what the vet is trying to determine. We don't have the dog's medical history, we haven't seen the animal, all we can say is that the test results will be back in a few days and that the dog isn't doing himself any serious harm.

Comment: Related: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/repetitive-paw-licking?rq=1

Comment: http://dogcare.dailypuppy.com/neurodermatitis-dogs-7984.html